# How to validate a hidden filed when filed active only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I just have one pick box. When the Other choice is selected, a new text field where the other option can be entered will appear. My problem is that when the other choice is the only one selected, I need to provide validation for the hidden field. I have to submit every field in my form. Help me solve this, please. The form's code is listed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue(val)
    {
        if(val==="others")
           document.getElementById('color').style.display='block';
        else
           document.getElementById('color').style.display='none'; 
    }

  </script> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="" class="signin-form">
        <div class="form-group">
           <select name="color" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)' required>
                <option>pick a color</option>  
                <option value="red">RED</option>
                <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
                <option value="others">others</option>
            </select>      
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="color" id="color" class="form-control" style='display:none'/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it required the same way you show it. So you could do something like this:

```
function checkvalue(val) 
{
    const color = document.getElementById('color');
    if(val==="others") {
       color.style.display='block';
       color.required = true;
   } else {
       color.style.display='none';
       color.required = false;
   }
}
```